# Restarting Spark structured streaming query on exception or termination

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

What's the right way of programmatically restarting a structured streaming query which has terminated due to an exception? Example code or reference would be appreciated.

Could it be done from within the `onQueryTerminated()` event handler of `StreamingQueryListener` class?